# What is the difference using the operators `+=` vs `=+` in Java?

Tags: java, operators, assignment-operator

I just realized that I was using `=+` instead of the operator `+=` and my program was doing all sorts of weird and unexpected things.
Eclipse didn't give me an error of any kind so I assume that `=+` is a legitimate operator, but there is no reference to that in my book.

My question is:
What does `=+` do and under what circumstances would you use it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A common syntax is:

```java
 +=
```

This is the **add and assignment operator**, which adds right-hand expression to the left-hand variable then assigns the result to left-hand variable. For example:

```java
 int i = 1;
 int j = 2;
 i += j;

 // Output: 3
 System.out.println( i )
```

A far less common syntax is:

```java
=+
```

Usually this is written as two different operators, separated by a space:

```java
= +
```

Without the space, it looks as follows:

```java
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
    
i =+ j;

// Output: 2
System.out.println(i);
```

An idiomatic way to write this is to shift the unary operator to the right-hand side:

```java
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
    
i = +j;

// Output: 2
System.out.println(i);
```

Now it's easy to see that `i` is being assigned to the positive value of `j`. However, `+` is superfluous, so it's often dropped, resulting in `i = j`, effectively the equivalent of `i = +1 * j`. In contrast is the negative unary operator:

```java
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
    
i = -j;

// Output: -2
System.out.println(i);
```

Here, the `-` would be necessary because it inverts the signedness of `j`, effectively the equivalent of `i = -1 * j`.

See the [operators tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) for more details.

Answer (score 15):

`=+` is the same as the assignment operator `=`

```
a =+ b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (+b);
```

which is the same as

```
a = b;
```

Comment: Indeed, given that a=-1; is a valid line I think it was decided that a=+1 should also be valid despite doing nothing. I sometimes use it to emphasis some intent

Answer (score 6):

The important fact to highlight is that there is no `=+` assignment operator in Java.

You're just listing two operators, one after the other (an `=` then a `+`)

- `i =+ j;` is just like writing  `i = +j;`.

While a little funky looking at it that way, it's very clear to everyone when considering the minus sign.

- `i =- j;`  is the same as `i = -j;`

As mentioned in many other answers, the Add and Assignment operator `+=`

- Adds the right hand side expression to the value of the left hand variable
- Then assigns the value of that addition to the left hand variable.

Answer (score 3):

`+=` adds the right operand to left operand and assign it to left operand

`=+` assign a value to the left operand

Answer (score 1):

Actually saying that `i=j` is the same as `i= +j` is not totally true,
because `i= +j` promotes the variable type to int if it's smaller than int, while assignment does not.
For example:

```
byte b1 = 2;
short s1 = b; // compiles and s1 equals 2 of type short
short s2 = +b; // Compile error: required type: short, provided int
// Because the result of +b equals 2 of type int
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no effect of =+ other than that it is same as =

Comment: Do not use answers to ask for help; use comments, if you want to add a comment, or just open a new question.